# better way of counting unique item

Tags: c++, c++11, std, c++17

I just find a way to count that number of unique items in a vector. This is my most naïve approach.

```
std::vector<Items> v;

// some other work
std::vector<Items> unique_Count;
unique_Count.clear();
std::unique_copy(v.begin, v.end(), std::back_inserter(unique_Count);
int uniqueCount = unique_Count.size();
```

Is this the only with or this there a better way in the standard library?

Comment: can you not use std::set<Type> (ordered) or unordered_set<Type> - http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/? maps also work? very standard in Java and C++. Once you have the set of elements, you can compare the sizes and find out 1) How many of the elements are duplicate 2) Which items are duplicates.

Comment: for OP, a set doesn't create duplicates so only contains unique items.

Comment: @chris         True, but it is all about finding a "Mechanism" to do unique element counting using C++ STL and OP can write his/her own methods.

Comment: The `unique_copy` method would only work if you sort the vector first. But using sets is much easier.

Comment: While using a `set` might get you cool looking code that only occupies a few lines, there's a good chance `sort` + `unique` (or `unique_copy`) on a `vector` will get you better performance due to better [spatial locality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_of_reference), especially for types that are cheap to move. If you care about such things then measure the performance of the two approaches and decide for yourself.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It can depend on what you mean by "better", but there are certainly ways that are simpler, and other ways that are probably faster.

The really simple way would be to insert the items into a `std::set` or `std::unordered_set`. When you've inserted all of them, the size of the set will be the number of unique items.

The probably faster method would be to use `std::sort` and `std::unique` to find the unique items "in place" instead of copying them. This is *pretty* much what `std::unique_copy` will normally do internally anyway, but doing it in place saves a fair amount on allocation and copying.

```
std::vector<Items> v;

// populate v with data

std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
int uniqueCount = std::unique(v.begin(), v.end()) - v.begin();
```

Comment: `std::unique` returns the end of unique range while the begin is not modified. The result expression should be `int uniqueCount = std::unique(v.begin(), v.end()) - v.begin()` instead.

Comment: I do not want to sort the vector at least initially but rather just count the number of unique items in the vector

Comment: @user4425844: I guess that the problem of counting unique items cannot be solved faster than sorting (when using a comparison-based method). So sorting should not be rejected.

Answer (score 3):

```
struct iterator_hash {
  template<class Iterator>
  size_t operator()(Iterator it) const {
    using value_type = typename std::decay< decltype(*it) >::type;
    return std::hash<value_type>{}( *it );
  }
};
struct iterator_element_equals {
  template<class Iterator>
  size_t operator()(Iterator lhs, Iterator rhs) const {
    return *lhs == *rhs;
  }
};
std::vector<Items> v;
std::unordered_set<std::vector<Items>::iterator, iterator_hash, iterator_element_equals> s;
for(auto it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it) {
  s.insert(it); // not *it
}
size_t uniqueCount = s.size();
```

here I create a hash on vector iterators that hashes and compares on the underlying elements (do not pass it the `.end()` iterator).

Then I insert the iterators from the set into it, and ask it how big it is.

We could instead use a `std::set<Iterator, iterator_less>` or something if you prefer.

Answer (score -1):

The last answer to this post I saw was around 6 years ago. I have been looking for a solution to this as I came across it recently in one project that I have been working on, and I would like to share my solution. I think is a more modern, templated solution, one could use as a black box, or so, for data stored in `std::vector` containers.

Let's say you have the following code in header file `uniques.hpp`

```
#ifndef UNIQUES_HPP
#define UNIQUES_HPP

#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
std::vector<T> unique_values( std::vector<T> & input_vec ){

    std::vector<T> uniques( input_vec.size() );
    typename std::vector<T>::iterator it;
    it = std::unique_copy (input_vec.begin(), input_vec.end(), uniques.begin() );

    std::sort( uniques.begin(), it );

    it = std::unique_copy( uniques.begin(), it, uniques.begin() );

    uniques.resize( std::distance(uniques.begin(), it) );

    return uniques;
}

template<typename T>
std::vector<int> count_unique_values( std::vector<T> & input_vec ){

    std::vector<T> uniques = unique_values<T>( input_vec );
    std::vector<int> counts( uniques.size() );

    for(size_t i = 0; i < counts.size(); ++i)
        counts[i] = std::count( input_vec.begin(), input_vec.end(), uniques[i] );

    return counts;
}

#endif
```

One could find unique values in vectors of integers, floats, or even strings using the first function appearing in the header file above `unique_values`. On top of that, I have a second function `count_unique_values` which returns the number of occurrences per unique value.

Below I show three examples for `int`, `float` and `std::string` data stored in vectors.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

#include "uniques.hpp"

template<typename T>
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & o, const std::vector<T> & v){
    
    o << "[ ";
    for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size()-1; i++)
        o << v[i] << ", ";

    o << v[v.size()-1];

    std::cout << " ]" << std::endl;
    
    return o;
}

int main(){

// Example with integers
    std::cout << "Example with integers" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "---------------------" << std::endl;
    
    std::vector<int> v_init_int = {1,5,5,1,1,1,3,5,4,3,3,3,0};
    std::cout << "Initial vector: " << v_init_int;
    
    std::vector<int> v_uniques_int = unique_values<int>( v_init_int );
    std::cout << "Vector of unique values: " << v_uniques_int;
    
    std::vector<int> v_counts_int = count_unique_values<int>( v_init_int );
    std::cout << "Vector of unique counts: " << v_counts_int;
    std::cout << "\n\n";


// Example with floats
    std::cout << "Example with floats" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "---------------------" << std::endl;
    
    std::vector<float> v_init_floats = {1.4,5.2,5.2,1.0,1.0,1.0,3.2,5.2,4.0,3.3,3.2,3.3,0.1};
    std::cout << "Initial vector: " << v_init_floats;
    
    std::vector<float> v_uniques_floats = unique_values<float>( v_init_floats );
    std::cout << "Vector of unique values: " << v_uniques_floats;
    
    std::vector<int> v_counts_floats = count_unique_values<float>( v_init_floats );
    std::cout << "Vector of unique counts: " << v_counts_floats;
    std::cout << "\n\n";


// Example with strings
    std::cout << "Example with strings" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "--------------------" << std::endl;
    
    std::vector<std::string> v_init_strings = {"hi","hey","hey","hola","hola","hi","hi","hi","hola","hey","hey","hola","hi"};
    std::cout << "Initial vector: " << v_init_strings;
    
    std::vector<std::string> v_uniques_strings = unique_values<std::string>( v_init_strings );
    std::cout << "Vector of unique values: " << v_uniques_strings;
    
    std::vector<int> v_counts_strings = count_unique_values<std::string>( v_init_strings );
    std::cout << "Vector of unique counts: " << v_counts_strings;

    return 0;
}
```

The output of the above `main.cpp` program would be:

```
Example with integers
---------------------
Initial vector: [ 1, 5, 5, 1, 1, 1, 3, 5, 4, 3, 3, 3, 0 ]
Vector of unique values: [ 0, 1, 3, 4, 5 ]
Vector of unique counts: [ 1, 4, 4, 1, 3 ]


Example with floats
---------------------
Initial vector: [ 1.4, 5.2, 5.2, 1, 1, 1, 3.2, 5.2, 4, 3.3, 3.2, 3.3, 0.1 ]
Vector of unique values: [ 0.1, 1, 1.4, 3.2, 3.3, 4, 5.2 ]
Vector of unique counts: [ 1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3 ]


Example with strings
--------------------
Initial vector: [ hi, hey, hey, hola, hola, hi, hi, hi, hola, hey, hey, hola, hi ]
Vector of unique values: [ hey, hi, hola ]
Vector of unique counts: [ 4, 5, 4 ]
```

Comment: Have you ever tested this code? You are copying the elements twice as well as invoking undefined behaviour with the overlapping ranges in `unique_copy`

Comment: @ABaumstumpf can you please provide some more information about the undefined behaviour? Of course I tested it, in fact I actually use it quite extensively, and never realized any issue!  Please let me know more about this BUG you are mentioning.

Comment: @ABaumstumpf Check this out: https://cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/unique_copy/   It's not the fastest solution, but it is pretty safe I think, I doubt there is a bug...

Comment: @ABaumstumpf And by the way, I visually show how I tested it!

Comment: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/algorithms#alg.unique-8
Under preconditions:
>Preconditions: The ranges [first, last) and [result, result + (last - first)) do not overlap.


`it = std::unique_copy( uniques.begin(), it, uniques.begin() );`
here the ranges overlap, violating the precondition.

Undefined behaviour does not mean that it will nto compile or that it will give you wrong results - it means there is no guarantee on what will happen. The correct result is one potential outcome, but it can also just crash or give garbage data if it so choses.

Comment: @ABaumstumpf Okay I will look at it closer, thanks! Then, the `cplusplus` website need to fix their documentation as well https://cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/unique_copy/ ! This is what I followed to implement my code.