# how to find the number of unique elements in each row of a matrix in C++

Tags: c++, matrix

Given a matrix of size MxN, I have to write a program  to count the unique elements on each row of that matrix.
| input   | output    |
| M=3,N=4 |   -       |
| 1|2|2|1 | row-1:2   |
| 1|2|3|4 | row-2:2   |

---

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int  main() {
    int M,N;
    cin>>M>>N;
    int a[M][N];
    for(int i=1;i<=M; i++){
        for(int j=1;j<=N;j++){            
        cin>>a[i][j];
      }
    }

   for(int i=1;i<=M;i++){
      int count=1;
        for(int j=1;j<N;j++){
           if(a[i][j]==a[i][j+1]) continue;  
           else  count++;     
        }
        cout<<"row-"<<i<<":"<<count;
      }


   }
```

when I entered a row like {1,2,2,1} the output shows 3.
if I initialize count=0, then output for {1,2,3,4} shows 4.

Comment: `int a[M][N];` is not standard c++. Use `std::vector` here. I would also recommend using a [good c++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Your test seems to be valid only if value are sorted in ascending order within a row. It's probably why you need different init values for count. Besides your question is probably a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28100712/better-way-of-counting-unique-item

Comment: C++ is 0-indexed. `int a[M]; for(int i=1;i<=M;i++) { foo(a[i]); }` does out of bound access.